# fill sqlite table values from text document

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with simple sqlite database for dictionary like application. My table stores values as below

### **value** -   **Meaning**

abc     -    xyz

I tried working with simple insert statement and values are getting filled,but now my problem is that i have thousands of entries, is there any faster way from which i can fill the values in database. for instance, like `filling database from text file`. or i have to fill this way only.

i just want to fill data once and there are minimal chances of editing it.please help

Comment: Just use a transaction and prepared insert statement! [INSERT is really slow](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19) [beginTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction())

Comment: but i want it before developing my android part. i am accessing sqlite db through console

Comment: `BEGIN; INSERT INTO ...; INSERT ...; ...; COMMIT;` in SQLite shell

Comment: so i have to opt for piece of code then. is there any tool available for this?

Comment: You don't need! In console, just put `BEGIN;` before your inserts and `COMMIT;` after. I assume from your question that you have already build your SQL insert statements.

Comment: but i have hundreds of values,so i need to execute insert every time right? what i want is that somehow i need to fill my values from text file to db

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a quick way to get your text file into the database, you could run a regular expression that would use find-and-replace to convert your text file into a SQL script that would do the insertion.  For instance something like:

```
/(.*) - (.*)/INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('$1', '$2')/
```

A sed command to do this would be:

```
sed "s:\(.*\) - \(.*\):INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('\1', '\2'):g" [yourfile] > output.sql
```

And then of course, run output.sql

Comment: but how and where to use it? but +1 for informing